# Problems with closing

Tags: vue.js

I making an e-commerce app, and finished the backend and frontend, now want to insert products and join them together to publish an app. But when I open the modal component for adding products, then I can't close the component and when adding products in the console I see only an empty object. So I share a GitHub link to check little errors in code

https://github.com/HZHBKANJINA/prodaja_rakije

I tried a lot of methods. Firstly, I had a lot of errors and I fixed them, but this I can't fix anyway